# How to display a warning when returning an act_window (from python code) ? Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

In the product.template model , I added new smart button which return an ir.actions.act_window action to the model stock.quant , when clicking on the same button I want also to return a warning if there is a warning in the product based on conditions :
Here is the code of warning:

```
if not self or not self.env.user.has_group('sale.group_warning_sale'):
            return

        if self.sale_line_warn != 'no-message':
            if self.sale_line_warn_msg:
                message = self.sale_line_warn_msg
                warning = {
                    'title': ("Warning for %s") % self.name,
                    'message': message
                }

            if self.sale_line_warn == 'block':
                self = False

            return {'warning': warning}
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="view_product_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view_product_inherit</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <div name="button_box" position="inside">
                <button class="oe_stat_button" name="my_action"
                        type="object" icon="fa-shopping-cart" string="Stock">
                </button>
            </div>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Here is my function:

```
  def my_action(self):
        return {
            'name': _('Stock'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'stock.quant',
            'context': {'default_name': 'My warning message'},
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        }
```

*Any help please ? Is it possible to do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe do a smartbutton that shows number of objects with error message. And when you click on it, then show custom tree view with objects and their warnings. In current case you can show only 1 warning per click.

Comment: @Paxmees, how can I do that please?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution I can think of, is adding a `boolean` field and a `datetime` field to the `product.template` model. And in the action if there were any warnings check if the `boolean` field is `True` and if the time passed from the `datetime` field is less than for example 30 seconds, then don't show the warning and return your `ir.actions.act_window` action. But if the `boolean` field is `False` then show warning by raising a `UserWarning` or `ValidationError` and at the end of the warning message ask the user "*if you are sure and want to continue, click on the button again*". And don't forget to set the `boolean` field to `True` and the `datetime` field to the current time when showing returning the warning. Also set the `boolean` field to `False` when returning the action.

This way the user only gets the warning once and if he wants to continue anyway he can click on the button again.

Answer (score -2):

Add a condition at the top of your my_action method (before returning the action) like this:

```
if condition:   
      raise ValidationError("Error message")
```

Don't forget to import ValidationError at the top of your .py file.

```
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError
```

Comment: this will block the return of ir.actions.act_window action, So using ValidationError will not allows to redirect to 'stock.quant' model :/